# Magento SOAP (v1) API causes fatal error getSelect() after completed order

Tags: magento-1.8, api, soap, fatal-error

I'm trying to complete my software which interacting with the Magento API and another external API (REST). In this project I forwarding the orders of the other shop system towards Magento and I'm able to create a order (yeha!).

Unfortunately, Magento seems to cause an fatal error after the successful order. That's a problem because I've to convert about hundrets orders...

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [SOAP-ENV:Server] Call to a member function getSelect() on a non-object in /var/orders.php:280
Stack trace:
#0 /var/orders.php: SoapClient->__call('call', Array)
#1 /var/orders.php: SoapClient->call('6ceb613d278de9e...', 'cart.order', Array)
#2 /var/orders.php: complete_order(Array, 3)
#3 /var/orders.php: new_orders(Object(mysqli))
```

Does anybody have any idea how to solve that?

The involved line in the PHP file:

```
    $result = $client->call($session, 'cart.info', $shopping_cart_id);
```

The whole PHP code:

```
function complete_order($val,$i=1) {
    if($i == 3) {
    $client = new SoapClient(MAGENTO_HOST.'/api/soap/?wsdl');
    $session = $client->login(MAGENTO_API_USER, MAGENTO_API_KEY);

    # Choose a store id 
    $store_id = $client->call($session, 'category.currentStore', MAGENTO_STORE_ID);

    # Create a new shopping cart
    $shopping_cart_id = $client->call( $session, 'cart.create', $store_id );

    # Add products to cart #
    $product_for_cart = array(
        array(
            "sku" => "TOPP19600",
            "qty" => 2,
            "options" => null
        ),
        array(
            "sku" => "TOPP19601",
            "qty" => 1,
            "options" => null
        )
    );

    $val['items'] = $product_for_cart;

    foreach($val['items'] AS $item) {
        $filters = array( 
            'status' => array( '=' => 1 ),  
            'sku' => array( '=' => $item['sku']), 
        ); 
        $result = $client->call($session, 'catalog_product.list', array($filters,$store_id));
        if($result != NULL AND count($result) > 0) {
            $product_for_cart[] = array('product_id' => $result[0]['product_id'], 'qty' => $item['qty']);
        } else {
            # unknown product found #
            echo('Unknown product'); 
        }
    }

    # Customer information (as guest) #
    $customer = array(
    'mode' => 'guest',
    'firstname' => $val['invoice_address']['firstname'],
    'lastname' => $val['invoice_address']['lastname'],
    'email' => $val['invoice_address']['email'],
    'website_id' => 0,
    'store_id' => 0,
    'group_id' => 0,
    'dob' => date('d.m.Y',$val['created_at']),
    'confirmation' => 1
    );

    $resultCustomerSet = $client->call($session, 'cart_customer.set', array($shopping_cart_id, $customer, $store_id) );

    // Set customer addresses, for example guest's addresses
    $arrAddresses = array(
        array(
            "mode" => "shipping",
            "firstname" => "testFirstname",
            "lastname" => "testLastname",
            "company" => "testCompany",
            "street" => "testStreet",
            "city" => "testCity",
            "region" => "testRegion",
            "postcode" => "testPostcode",
            "country_id" => "id",
            "telephone" => "0123456789",
            "fax" => "0123456789",
            "is_default_shipping" => 0,
            "is_default_billing" => 0
        ),
        array(
            "mode" => "billing",
            "firstname" => "testFirstname",
            "lastname" => "testLastname",
            "company" => "testCompany",
            "street" => "testStreet",
            "city" => "testCity",
            "region" => "testRegion",
            "postcode" => "testPostcode",
            "country_id" => "id",
            "telephone" => "0123456789",
            "fax" => "0123456789",
            "is_default_shipping" => 0,
            "is_default_billing" => 0
        )
    );

    $add_product_to_cart = $client->call($session,"cart_product.add",array($shopping_cart_id, $product_for_cart));

    $resultCustomerAddresses = $client->call($session,"cart_customer.addresses",array($shopping_cart_id, $arrAddresses, $store_id));

    $choose_shipping_method = $client->call($session, 'cart_shipping.method', array($shopping_cart_id, 'pl_store_pickup_kostenlose_selbstabholung_w_hrend_den_gesch_ftszeiten_sie_erhalten_eine_e_mail_benachrichtigung_sobald_ihre_bestellung_zur_abholung_bereit_liegt__jawolle_rheinstr_29_66113_saarbr_cken'));

    $resultPaymentMethod = $client->call($session,'cart_payment.method',array($shopping_cart_id, $paymentMethod = array('method' => 'bankpayment')));

    # Finishing order # 
    $result = $client->call($session, 'cart.info', $shopping_cart_id);

    $client->endSession($session);
```

Comment: Please post the code of `orders.php`, because it seems as the error is thrown there in line 280.

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt I added the "bad" line.

Comment: Ok, I slowly understand. Than it is time to dig in magento. This is no standard behaviour, therefore I think we can't help you, because the problem is not reproducable

Comment: That would not be the first time. In the first approach I was not able to add a customer because Magento ask for a "day of birth", which is nowhere noticed (espacially not in the Magento documentations). Therefore I digged several minutes the PHP code of Magento and was able to identify the missing veriable "dob". Is there a workaround to "ignore" the fatal error and continue the script?

Comment: Nope, Fatal errors can't be catched.

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt I expect the answers; just hoped be able  to pass the SOAP errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand what's wrong....

I have a plugin (TrustedShop) who use an observer on 'checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after'

I remove in the plugin the part :

```
        <checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after>
           <observers>
                <buyerprotect>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Symmetrics_Buyerprotect_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>registerTsSoapModel</method>
                </buyerprotect>
            </observers>
        </checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after>
```

And it's fine...